# How to resolve DNS using Network Manager?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq, networkmanager, resolv.conf

I am using Network Manager(`nmcli`) to establish network connection to a Linux based embedded device. But the client application is having issues connecting to aws backend. In the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` the `dns=dnsmasq` is set and the `/etc/resolv.conf` contains

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Is this correct?

But the aws endpoint dns has dynamic IPs and I think this is causing an issue to resolve dns. However, I can ping to aws endpoint successfully so I am confused whether if it is really a dns lookup issue or bug from my application. Should I add any entry to `resolv.conf`? Because the same application is running on other devices with no issues.

```
nslookup example.amazonaws.com
```

shows

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.amazonaws.com
Address: x.xxx.133.168
Name:   example.amazonaws.com
Address: x.xxx.141.141
Name:   example.amazonaws.com
Address: xx.xxx.236.119
Name:   example.amazonaws.com
Address: x.xxx.216.149
Name:   example.amazonaws.com
Address: xx.xx.120.62
```

But the application times out while resolving dns and no further error message is reported.

Can anyone please help me to debug the issue?

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here

Answer (score 0):

You've not actually explained what the problem is here.

The DNS setup using NM and DNSMasq is just fine.

Here DNSMasq is acting as a caching DNS proxy, but assuming the TTL values on the Dynamic DNS are set suitably low enough it should work just fine. It may return an old IP address until the TTL expires, but this is the same behaviour of any caching DNS server.

Comment: Hello @hardillb, thanks for quick response. The application times out while resolving dns and no further error message is reported.